# react-native-file-viewer don't work in my app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

i try to use react-native-file-viewer for view à pdf file in my app.
I have import the lib like this : `import  FileViewer from 'react-native-file-viewer';`

And i had make à function :

```
getPdf(){
        const path = '../images/Charte.pdf';
        FileViewer.open(path).then((res) => {
            console.log(res);
        }).catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
        });
    }
```

But when it's give me this error :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VpPnZ.png)

do you have any leads?

Comment: Have you linked this package with `react-native link react-native-file-viewer` ?
You can also use the webview to read pdf, it works fine for Ios.

Comment: @Dyo thx for your response, yes i did that like in the doc. Ah ? ok and it's works on android to ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm personnaly using [react-native-pdf-view](https://github.com/cnjon/react-native-pdf-view) for android and a webView for ios, you can also use a google doc trick to read pdf in android webView but it requires a connection (more info [here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/6488))